# Linq to SQL Contains on name search

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, contains

I'm searching on a SQL 2005 DB that has a fullname column in it. I want to be able to check against that column and order the results according to their relevance.

I'm using a nice ordering system that I found on SO but that unfortunately is not working as I'd like, and it seems to be because of the 'contains' functionality not matching.

Here's the code:

```
 private static int QueryOrder(string query, string name)
{
    if (name == query)
        return -1;
    if (name.Contains(query))
        return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Now the problem is that this doesn't work in the following scenario:

Database fullname column data: *Joey JoeJoe Junior Shabbadoo*

Search query: *Joey Shabbadoo*

The queryorder method doesn't match on the 'contains' as it doesn't see the fullname field as containing the query text.

The way I'm then ordering the results is like this

```
 peopleList = peopleList.OrderBy(p => QueryOrder(fullName, p.FullName)).ToList();
```

So, is there a way using LINQ to do this or should I just go down the sproc route?

Comment: you could split the search query on the space and do a check for both parts?

Comment: I've updated the question with a little more detail. I'd considered splitting but I'm not sure how I'd then order the results.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is right. "*Joey Shabbado*" is not `contained` in your search string. For contains to return true, complete sequence of characters must match one complete sequence in the other string.

Depending on what you define as 'matches' you could turn to regular expressions and try (1) splitting your query and then matching against `\AJoey.+Shabbadoo\z` using regex

Comment: I'm not saying LINQ is wrong, just that the contains functionality doesn't work in my scenario.

Comment: I've used regex before but not for something like this. I will investigate how suitable it is.